# WordPress Query get posts based on custom table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have some regular WordPress posts that I need to get from the database by parent category, and order by the results of a custom table in the database that I have made.

The parent category that I want to retrieve posts for (including children) is called explorer with the id of 29.

The custom table is called `wp_upvotes`. in this table there are a few columns, but the only columns that we care about would probably be `id` and `postID`. I want to order the `wp_posts` by the number of rows that has the `postID` equal to the `wp_post.ID`, and if there are no rows in that table for the other posts, then they should be ordered by date at the end. I want the most number of `upvotes` to the least number of `upvotes` by date.

The query I have tried is this (it returns only the first post, not all of them):

```
$catIDs = array(29,30,31,32);

SELECT wp_posts.*, COUNT(wp_upvotes.id) AS upvotes FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_upvotes ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_upvotes.postID)
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (" . implode(',', $catIDs) . "))
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY upvotes DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

When I remove the LEFT JOIN for the `wp_upvotes` table it returns all of the correct posts.. Why is it only returning one row when I am using a LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (" . implode(',', $catIDs) . "))
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the main factor was to use `ORDER BY wp_posts.ID` for whatever reason to make it show all of the rows instead of just one.. Odd but here's my final code to do what I wanted to do above:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*, COUNT(wp_upvotes.id) AS upvotes FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy
ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_term_taxonomy.parent = 29)
LEFT JOIN wp_upvotes ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_upvotes.postID)
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY upvotes DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
```